# Where is System.CodeDom.Compiler.CompilerParameters in Silverlight?

Tags: silverlight, reflection, compilation, reflection.emit, codedom

I want to create Mathematics Expression Evaluator in Silverlight.
To do that easily, I need compilation on the fly using System.Reflection, System.Reflection.Emit, System.CodeDom.Compiler, and other related assemblies.

However, I cannot find this class available in Silverlight.

Give me some suggestion please.

Comment: The security model in SL is very stringent about Reflection.  The classes exist, but you are likely to run into a fair bit of unexpected exceptions about security.

Answer (score 7):

Silverlight doesn't do the CodeDom, `System.Reflection` and `System.Reflection.Emit` are present in the mscorlib for Silverlight.

Hence if you are going to do a expression evaluator you'll need to emit IL for the expressions.

Alternatively if you can use Javascript you could get the host browser to perform the evaluation.